# Simple if statement not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple counter, that counts `1` to `5`. Once the number is `5`, the next number should rewind back to `1`.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to rewind and the counter is `1`: it goes to 0, not back to `5`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/YMB3e/2/

```
var $i = 1;

$('.increase').click(function () {
    ++$i;
    $('p').text($i);
    if ($i == 5) {
        $i = 0;
    }
});

$('.decrease').click(function () {
    --$i;
    $('p').text($i);
    if ($i == 0) {
        $i = 5;
    }
});
```

What is the best way to avoid the counter going to `0`, and instead go back to `5`?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
var $i = 1;

$('.increase').click(function () {
    ++$i;
    if ($i > 5) {
        $i = 1;
    }
    $('p').text($i);
});

$('.decrease').click(function () {
    --$i;
    if ($i <= 0) {
        $i = 5;
    }
    $('p').text($i);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/YMB3e/25/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong order of code. `$('p').text($i);` should be after `if ($i == 0) { $i = 5 }`

As @Anton said in the comments:

> If you click decrease until it's 5 then click increase it will go
>   above 5

So you need a few more changes:

```
var $i = 1;

$('.increase').click(function () {
    ++$i;
    if ($i > 5) {
        $i = 1;
    }
    $('p').text($i);
});

$('.decrease').click(function () {
    --$i;
    if ($i <= 0) {
        $i = 5;
    }
    $('p').text($i);
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YMB3e/22/)

Comment: @Anton Fixed. Thanks for the note

Answer (score 0):

change it like this

```
$('.decrease').click(function () {

$('p').text($i);
 --$i;
if ($i == 0) {
    $i = 5;
}
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YMB3e/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to amend your if statement here - if `$i` is 1 go to 5 otherwise take one off `$i`. Adjust the `increase` function likewise.

```
$('.increase').click(function () {
  if ($i == 5) {
    $i = 1;
  } else {
    ++$i;
  }
  $('p').text($i);
});

$('.decrease').click(function () {
  if ($i == 1) {
    $i = 5;
  } else {
    --$i;
  }
  $('p').text($i);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMB3e/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value after updating the variable:

```
var $i = 1;

$('.increase').click(function () {
    if (++$i == 6) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    $('p').text($i);
});

$('.decrease').click(function () {
    if (--$i == 0) {
        $i = 5;
    }
    $('p').text($i);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YMB3e/9/)

OR use mod operator - %

```
var $i = 0;

$('.increase').click(function () {
    $i++;
    $('p').text($i%5+1);
});

$('.decrease').click(function () {
    $i = --$i==-1 ? 5 : $i;
    $('p').text($i%5+1);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YMB3e/27/)

Answer (score 0):

## **Answer:**

You update the DOM, before you do your logic.

```
$('.increase').click(function () {
    ++$i;
    $('p').text($i); // <-- Update DOM
    if ($i == 5) {   // Logic after
        $i = 0;
    }
});
```

$i will never be `0` then. It will become `5` and then `1` on the next click

**Fix:**

```
$('.increase').click(function () {
    ++$i;            // Logic
    if ($i == 5)  
        $i = 0;
    $('p').text($i); // <-- Update DOM after
});
```

---

## **My Suggestion, as an alternative**

To improve on the code, and make it easier to maintain, I would put it into a module, and make the code more **scalable and reusable**.

```
function Counter($count, $inc, $dec, settings) { // <- Make it into a Module
    settings = settings || {};
    var count = settings.initialCount || 0;
    var max = settings.max || 5;
    var min = settings.min || 0;
    $inc.click(function () {
       updateCount(1);
    });

    $dec.click(function () {
        updateCount(-1);
    });

    function updateCount(value){
        if(count+value > max) count = min;
        else if(count + value < min) count = max;
        else count += value;
        $count.html(count);
    }
    updateCount(0);

}
Counter($('.count'), $('.increase'), $('.decrease')); // <- Initiate the module
```

## **Fiddle with demo of reusability**

**http://jsfiddle.net/R5swH/3/**

Comment: @Anton Because it's reusable. And an alternative to the other suggestion. Also if you look at it, and forget the settings, its less code than OP's original.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('.increase').click(function (e) {
    $('p').text(($i==5?$i=0:++$i));
});

$('.decrease').click(function (e) {
    $('p').text(($i==0?$i=5:--$i));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/YMB3e/17/)